# Converting string to int and a double

Tags: java, string

I have a text file with several lines each containing 3 numbers. Each number is separated by a space.

```
    1 1 4.0
```

When I read this string from the file I want to convert the first two numbers into integers and the last to a double. How can I go about doing this?

Comment: What happens when you type "convert string to int in Java" in Google? Seriously?

Comment: Actually for a new Java user, this one is really helpful. I don't think it is a meaningless post since it is a post that uses .split() function to fix the problem about "using 1 string to parse several integers". I strongly suggest to re-open this post.

Answer (score 5):

```
String [] numbers = "1 1 4.0".split(" ");
int first = Integer.parseInt(numbers[0]);
int second = Integer.parseInt(numbers[1]);
double third = Double.parseDouble(numbers[2]);
```

This is assuming the numbers will always be in that form.

**Explanation**

The `String` class has a `split` method that takes a regular expression as an argument and "splits" the string up into an array of results.  Then you can make the numbers actual `int` and `double` values by using their object wrappers to cast them appropriately from a string object by accessing the corresponding array value.

Answer (score 2):

- You need to first split your string on space, to get each value as
  individual element in a String array. You would have to use [`String#split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) for that.
- Now, iterate over your array, and for each element, check whether it contains a `dot(.)`.
- If it contains a `dot`, convert it to `double`, using [`Double#valueOf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#valueOf%28java.lang.String%29) or [`Double#parseDouble`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble%28java.lang.String%29)
- If it does not contains a `dot`, convert it to `integer` using [`Integer#valueOf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf%28java.lang.String%29) or [`Integer#parseInt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29)
- Using this approach, you won't have to worry about the order in which your `int` and `double` values are stored.

**An Example**: -

```
    String str = "21.3";
    if (str.contains(".")) {
        System.out.println(Double.parseDouble(str));
    } else {
        System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(str));
    }
```

**Difference between the two methods is that: -**

`Integer.parseInt` returns a `primitive int`, whereas `Integer.valueOf` returns an `Integer wrapper object`.

Comment: I like this solution since it doesn't assume the ints and doubles are always in the same order.

Comment: @Austin. Yeah exactly. It would be better to fore-check your values, rather than playing with exceptions later on. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like:

```
try {
        int posStart    = 0;
        int posEnd      = text.indexOf(" ", posStart);
        int firstNumber = Integer.valueOf(text.substring(posStart, posEnd));

        posStart    = posEnd + 1;
        posEnd      = text.indexOf(" ", posStart);
        int secondNumber = Integer.valueOf(text.substring(posStart, posEnd));

        posStart    = posEnd + 1;
        double thirdNumber = Double.valueOf(text.substring(posStart));

        System.out.println(firstNumber + " / " + secondNumber + " / " + thirdNumber);
    }
    catch (Exception err) {
        System.out.println(err.getMessage());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
    String numberSequence = "1 1 4.0";

    String[] numbers = numberSequence.split(" ");

    for(String no : numbers){
        if(no.contains(".")){
            Double.parseDouble(no);
        }
        else{
            Integer.parseInt(no);
        }
    }
```